# How to edit this method to work with a Customer array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I'm supposed to create a method that accepts the ID of a customer and then returns the index in the array if that Id is found. With the method only taking in Integer ID.

I used an iterative binary search to be able to search through my customer array list. But the problem is that it is getting stuck with the operand types when comparing the Customer array to an Integer. I have tried to change the type of method to static, CustomerList, Customer, etc. But that isn't affecting it at all.

cl in the code is the public field I created at the beginning of my class.

As --> public Customer[ ] cl;

```
**public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;    

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;    
    }

    protected Person() {

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstName: " + firstName + "\nLastName: " + lastName + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nCity: " + city + "\nState: " + state + "\nZipCode: " + zipCode;
    }

    public String toCSV() {
        return this.firstName + "," + this.lastName + "," + this.address + "," + this.city
                + "," + this.state + "," + this.zipCode;
    }

    public void copy(Person p) {       
        firstName = p.firstName;
        lastName = p.lastName;
        address = p.address;
        city = p.city;
        state = p.state;
        zipCode = p.zipCode;
    }

    public void copy(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public Person clone() {
        Person p = new Person(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.address, this.city, this.state, this.zipCode);
        return p;
    }
}**

**public class Customer extends Person{
    private int customerID;
    private double grossSales;

    public Customer(int customerID, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    public Customer(String s, int customerID, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        copyCSV(s);
    }

    protected Customer() {

    }

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public double getGrossSales() {
        return grossSales;
    }

    public void setGrossSales(double grossSales) {
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerID: " + customerID + "\nGrossSales: " + grossSales + super.toString();
    }

    public String toCSV() {
        return this.customerID + "," + this.grossSales + "," + super.toCSV();
    }

    public void copy(Customer c) {
        super.copy(c);
        customerID = c.customerID;
        grossSales = c.grossSales;
    }

    public void copy(int customerId, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super.copy(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        this.customerID = customerId;
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    public Customer clone() {
        Customer c = new Customer(this.customerID, this.grossSales, this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(), this.getAddress(), this.getCity(), this.getState(), this.getZipCode());
        return c;    
    }

    public int compareTo(Customer c) {
        int returnValue = 0;

        if (this.customerID > c.customerID) {
            returnValue = -1;
        } else if (this.customerID < c.customerID) {
            returnValue = 1;
        } else {
            returnValue = 0;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public void copyCSV(String s) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] a = s.split(",");

        list = Arrays.asList(a);

        this.copy(Integer.parseInt(list.get(0)), Double.parseDouble(list.get(1)), list.get(2), 
                list.get(3), list.get(4), list.get(5), list.get(6), list.get(7));
    }

}**

public int indexOf(Integer id) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = cl.length - 1; 

        while (min <= max) {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (cl[mid] < id) {
                min = mid + 1;
            } else if (cl[mid] > id) {
                max = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;   // target found
            }
        }

        return -(min + 1);    // target not found
    }
```

It is supposed to accept a customerID and returns the index in the array if found and insert point if not.

Essentially we have a CSV file with a list of customers and each customer is assigned an ID. We have both a person Class and customer Class which I included where we get and set all the variables. Along with toString and toCSV methods. In the final class CustomerList, there are several methods. This one, in particular, is supposed to take in an Integer like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. and if there is a person assigned to that ID number then it would return the index of that person in the Array created.

But it is getting stuck in the if and else if comparison statements.

Comment: @GhostCat I added in some more detail of my class. And including my other two classes person and customer. Which references the ID. I'm not sure if that helps enough to explain the problem.

Comment: Why not use Map with the Id as key instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a customer class such as:

```
 public class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

You can return an index of an ID in a customer array in a static method by passing both like:

```
    public static int indexOf(Customer[] arr, Customer cust) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = arr.length - 1; 

    while (min <= max) {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (arr[mid].getId() < cust.getId()) {
            min = mid + 1;
        } else if (arr[mid].getId() > cust.getId()) {
            max = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;   // target found
        }
    }

    return -(min + 1);    // target not found
}
```

You can also convert this to a nonstatic method and create a class for a Customer[] Object.  Or you can use it in your main (or any other method) like this:

```
    Customer cl1 = new Customer(1234,"John");
    Customer cl2 = new Customer(1235,"Khal");
    Customer cl3 = new Customer(1236,"John");
    Customer[] clArray = {cl1,cl2,cl3};

    Customer testCustomer = new Customer(1236,"AnyName");
    int index = indexOf(clArray, testCustomer);
    System.out.println(index); //Prints 2, which is the location of 1236 in the array
```

Customer currently is storing a name and an ID and can be changed to store any values you want, you just need to edit the constructor and private class variables.

Also I suggest looking into ArrayLists if you plan on holding information and changing it frequently.  Arrays are not the nicest things to handle.

EDIT:
Here is what the CustomerArray class should like according to your comments:

```
public class CustomerArray {

private Customer[] cl;

public CustomerArray() {
}

public CustomerArray(Customer...customers ) {
    this.cl = customers;
}

public Customer[] getCl() {
    return cl;
}

public void setCl(Customer[] cl) {
    this.cl = cl;
}


    public int indexOf(int id) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = cl.length - 1; 

    while (min <= max) {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if (cl[mid].getId() < id) {
            min = mid + 1;
        } else if (cl[mid].getId() > id) {
            max = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;   // target found
        }
    }

    return -(min + 1);    // target not found
}
}
```

And then the you can use it in the main method(or any other) like this:

```
    Customer cl1 = new Customer(1234,"John");
    Customer cl2 = new Customer(1235,"Khal");
    Customer cl3 = new Customer(1236,"John");
    CustomerArray clArray =  new CustomerArray(cl1,cl2,cl3);

    Customer testCustomer = new Customer(1236,"AnyName");
    int index = clArray.indexOf(testCustomer.getId());

    System.out.println(index);
```

So basically you are declaring a Class of CustomerArray which is holding all of your Customers.

Comment: This was the original code I had for the search. The problem is that there are strict rules on how the method should look and it only wants me to have one single parameter being the ID. 

I would use an ArrayList because it would make every single one of my methods way easier but of course, the rules for this final assignment restricts this to an array :)

Comment: If you only want one parameter then you can make a class holding the Customer[] array and make it a non static method, then calling it by doing clArray.indexOf(testCustomer.getId()).  Basically use two classes for holding Customer.  One for the array, and one for the ID and any other values you want a single Customer to hold.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: I editted it according to what the requirements are, check it out. (Also just switched the parameter to integer, forgot to do that)